# Getting multiply results via linq

Tags: c#, linq, youtube

I have a problem with linq, i want to get multiply results from youtube xml, but this code gives me only one result, anyone has idea how to fix this?

```
key = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+keys+@"&orderby=relevance";
var youtube = XDocument.Load(key);
var urls = (from item in youtube.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed")
                select new
                {
                    soundName = item.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry").Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title").ToString(),
                    url = item.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry").Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id").ToString(),
                });
```

youtube xml:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=keyword&orderby=relevance

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var urls = (from item in youtube.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed").Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
                select new
                {
                    soundName = item.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title").ToString(),
                    url = item.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id").ToString(),
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each of the `entry` elements (there may well be a much more concise way of writing this:

```
var test = (from item in youtube.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed")
            from entries in item.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
                select new
                {
                    soundName = entries.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title").ToString(),
                    url = entries.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id").ToString(),
                });
```

Should give you all the entries you're after.

Edit: Max's answer is more concise =D

Answer (score 0):

```
        XNamespace ytNs = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
        var youtube = XDocument.Load(key);
        var urls = (from item in youtube.Elements(ytNs + "feed").Elements(ytNs + "entry")
                    select new
                        {
                            soundName = item.Element(ytNs + "title").ToString(),
                            url = item.Element(ytNs + "id").ToString(),
                        });
```